# Unable to register Bower package: EINVFORMAT

Tags: javascript, bower, bower-register

I'm trying to register my first package with Bower. No matter what I do, I get the following error:

```
bower myPackageName#*         resolve git://github.com/username/myPackageName.git#*
bower myPackageName#*        download https://github.com/username/myPackageName/archive/0.1.0.tar.gz
bower myPackageName#*         extract archive.tar.gz
bower myPackageName#*        resolved git://github.com/username/myPackageName.git#0.1.0
[?] Registering a package will make it installable via the registry (https://bower.herokuapp.com), continue? Yes
bower myPackageName         register git://github.com/username/myPackageName.git
bower                       EINVFORMAT Invalid URL format
```

I don't understand why I'm getting this error. Can someone please explain to me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It looks like your trying to register a package whose name is in camel case notation. In other words, you may be trying to register `myPackageName`. However, words in bower package name should be separated by dashes ('-') instead of an upper-case letter. This would make your package name `my-package-name`.

Comment: When did they get rid of camel case notation?

Comment: This is a surprisingly unhelpful error message. Thanks very much for answering this question, it ranks highly on Google. I hope Bower devs will make this a priority.

Comment: I had the same issue too and this answer helped me. I can help to notice that there are a few packages with camelcase. what's up with them?